# Using sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to determine how many times a word occurs within a table for a uni assignment. I've been using sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document in SQL Server 2012 as I've used it previously in 2008. It worked fine before, but in this context SQL Server doesn't seem to like it very much.

```
SELECT display_term, SUM(occurrence_count) AS APP
FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document
( 
    DB_ID('Assign2A_341'),     OBJECT_ID('Post') 
)
GROUP BY display_term 
ORDER BY APP DESC
```

I keep running into this error: **Msg 30004, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
A fulltext system view or stvf cannot open user table object id 599673184.**

This is the format of the table being used:

```
CREATE TABLE Post(
Post_ID     FLOAT           NOT NULL,
Post_Txt    NVARCHAR(MAX)   NOT NULL,   
Post_Date   NVARCHAR(255)   NOT NULL,
Post_Author VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(Post_ID));
```

I can't see any reason why this shouldn't work, the context in which I previously used it was very similar to how I'm using it now, the only difference being the version of SQL Server I'm using and the content of the table.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the full-text index on Table Post after the create Table statement?

Also, as [BoL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280607.aspx) states, you need sufficient permissions to read from this index, are those present?

> Requires CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG permissions and SELECT permission on
>   the columns covered by the full-text index.